# Git push - everything is up to date?

Tags: github

Git newbie here - Ive setup a git repository which was working and have pushed a few commits. I made a code change now and am trying to push the new updates but I keep getting:

I did a:

```
git commit -m "message"
```

Then:

```
git push origin master

Everything up-to-date
```

Not sure where I have gone wrong.

```
git status


# On branch master
# Changes to be committed:
#   (use "git reset HEAD <file>..." to unstage)
#
#       modified:   Makefile
#       modified:   weather-station
#       modified:   weather-station.c
#
# Untracked files:
#   (use "git add <file>..." to include in what will be committed)
#
#       .gitignore
```

If I have a look at the code on github its old and the changes have not been sync'd.

Any idea where i went wrong or how I can fix this?

Comment: you have to stage files to be committed with `git add` or `git commit -a` (check for manuals). You can also use git gui to see what's going on

Comment: Thanks - I think I got it working now. Found this site which helped. http://githowto.com/